# Chrome Extension: retrieve AD credentials from session to auto-login on Wordpress

Tags: active-directory, google-chrome-extension, intranet

I need to create a Chrome extension that will allow us to get the user's credentials so that he will be automatically loging into the intranet (heavily-modified Wordpress).

I know for sure that Firefox can access Registry and AD credentials, but with the erratic updates and extensions that are constantly disabled by those, we can't afford to manually check every time firefox has an update.

I've searched on Google and so far I haven't found any answer. I've checked on Google labs and also on the Chrome extension store to see if there was a similar extension, but I found nothing either.

I've seen ADM released by chrome but this is for network administrators who want to centralize settings.

Any one has a clue on this?

Comment: By AD credentials, do you mean the actual username and password used to logon to an Active Directory domain?  If so, it shouldn't be possible to get those, and if it is, you're doing something *very* insecurely.

Comment: Not currently possible with a normal chrome extension.  The reason is that chrome extensions are just JavaScript and Html, and they cannot reach out of that sandbox beyond a few [Chrome.* APIs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index.html).  None of these let you reach back into the OS to get AD credentials.

I think it is possible though through an [NPAPI plugin](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi.html).  These can do pretty much anything they like.  If you find a Firefox NPAPI plugin that does this, you should be able to add a chrome manifest and install it in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not well documented, but after some research I found that this capability is built into Chrome.  All you need to do is add the Wordpress site to the "Intranet" zone on a Windows PC.

The setting is accessible from Chrome (even though it is a Windows setting):

`Settings/Advanced/Change Proxy Settings/Security/Local Intranet/Sites`